# Is there a better way to serialize (visually for the user) the removal and/or display of several new sprites in SKSpriteNode

Tags: ios, xcode, delay, skspritenode

I am developing a game that involves moving tokens around.

The user makes one move, and the tokens move according to predetermined rules.  I have developed this using sprite-kit.

My problem is, once the user makes one move, the algorithm removes token `SKSpriteNodes` and adds token `SKSpriteNodes` as needed, but the user only sees the end result.

I would like them to see each token movement individually, at a pace that the user chooses (quick animation or slow animation). I have it working, but I feel that there must be a better solution.

My solution is to keep track of how many seconds I need to delay the removal of a token, and pass that into the function such that the function is called with `.5` second delay for the first token, `1` delay for the second, `1.5` for the third, and so on.

The removeToken code is shown below, and the addToken code is similar.

```
(void)removeTokenIn:(NSTimeInterval)seconds {

    Token *tokenToRemove = (Token *)[self childNodeWithName:
        [NSString stringWithFormat:@"token%i",nbrTokens]];

    SKAction *waitAction = [SKAction waitForDuration:seconds];

    [tokenToRemove runAction:waitAction completion:^{
        [tokenToRemove removeFromParent];
    }]; 

    nbrTokens--;
}
```

Is there a better solution?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in a single SKAction, which is neater in code, easier to debug and can easily be extended to add more sophisticated effects:

Use a single [sequence SKAction](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/SpriteKit/Reference/SKAction_Ref/#//apple_ref/occ/clm/SKAction/sequence:) that contains: a [waitForDuration SKAction](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/SpriteKit/Reference/SKAction_Ref/#//apple_ref/occ/clm/SKAction/waitForDuration:) **and** a [removeFromParent SKAction](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/SpriteKit/Reference/SKAction_Ref/#//apple_ref/occ/clm/SKAction/removeFromParent).

You could then consider adding things like making them fade out rather than disappear (add a [fadeOutWithDuration SKAction](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/SpriteKit/Reference/SKAction_Ref/#//apple_ref/occ/clm/SKAction/fadeOutWithDuration:)), sound effects ([play SKAction](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/SpriteKit/Reference/SKAction_Ref/#//apple_ref/occ/clm/SKAction/play)) etc.